# Large difference between localhost and 127.0.0.1 on Windows?

Tags: python, windows, bottle

I am testing a small webserver in python 3.8 using the Bottle framework on Windows 10 and the response times feel very sluggish.

After boiling down the example to a minimum the server looks like this:

```py
from bottle import *
import time

@route("/now")
def time_service():
    response.content_type = 'text/plain'
    response.set_header('Cache-Control', 'max-age=10')
    return time.ctime()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(host='localhost', port=8080, debug=True, reloader=False)
```

Then a simple benchmark revealed giant response times:

```py
def get_resource():
    with urllib.request.urlopen('http://localhost:8080/now') as response:
       html = response.read()
    return html

%timeit get_resource()
2.03 s ± 3.8 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

So this seems very odd, so I tried replacing the name lookup with a fixed ip value:

```py
def get_resource():
    with urllib.request.urlopen('http://127.0.0.1:8080/now') as response:
       html = response.read()
    return html

%timeit get_resource()
512 µs ± 14.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Here we observe a decrease of 4000x in the response time. Where is the bottleneck here? Certainly it can't take 2 seconds to perform a name lookup on `localhost`?

Comment: What does `localhost` resolve to? I bet it's bound to IPv6 and it then finally falls back to IPv4 when that fails for some reason.

Comment: @tripleee: Hmm, not so sure: a `ping localhost` yields `Reply from ::1: time<1ms`. On the other hand `nslookup localhost` returns with `Name: localhost Address:127.0.0.1`.

Comment: I'm guessing it's fundamentally the same issue anyway; you can figure out what's wrong in your network configuration, or just make sure you use the same IP address on both ends.

Comment: https://imgur.com/WmRbmf5